# Transparent plane working on EEVEE but not cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm kind of new to Blender.
I'm trying to make a Reed and the flower ar the top is an Image plane. I've added  a transparent plane & it works fine on EEVEE render & won't work on Cycles (not 100% transparent). I've added the EEVEE Render, Cycles render & the Tree node to the page so that you can see the difference

[image]

Comment: Hello :). If you want help, please add a better image of your material nodetree.

Comment: ![Here's the NodeTree](https://imgur.com/hkgcnZg).

Comment: The EEVEE Render [Here](https://imgur.com/lomQD5a)

Comment: Thanks Susu for the info. It worked beautifully. I'm kinda new here so I don't know how to make your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add the translucency after the transparency.

Use transparent at the very end of the chain.